# Change Timezone in Lumen or Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen

I am using Lumen framework. How can I change Timezone to Europe/Paris CEST?

I added a variable in my `.env` file:

```
APP_TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris
```

But this doesn't work. What is the right way to update the timezone?

Comment: This should be enough in Lumen 5.2 at least. You may have to set your config/app.php file to use the env('APP_TIMEZONE') var in Laravel though.

Comment: It works on Lumen 5.1 too. After many days I finally realized that it's not enough to change the server's and DB's timezones - Lumen won't care until you set the timezone on the .env file

Comment: How do you know it's not working ? Is it database records that are off, or php generated time ? Do you have a minimal example to show how you see the wrong time ?

Comment: it did not for me. why? the time show in the database, late 8 hours...

Comment: make sure to `composer update ` and clear the config:cache

Answer (score 223):

You can set your **app time zone** by configuring **`app.php`** file in **`config`** folder .

To change time zone , modify the value of **timezone** in app.php file.

This is written in this section

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
```

For me i am using **Asia/Dhaka** as my application time zone.

Here is the appropriate syntax :

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Dhaka'
```

The list of [timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) for PHP.

Comment: Timezone 'America/Los_Angeles' for PST. Thank you

Comment: If you do this and it doesn't work, run `php artisan config:cache` after changing your app.php file. You need to reload the config under the new setting.

Comment: Do not forget to add `,` at the end of line. ;) . I mean `'timezone' => 'Asia/Dhaka',`

Answer (score 58):

There are two ways to update your code.
1. Please open the file **app.php** file present in **config** directory at lool of your project.
Go down the page and check **Application Timezone** 
where you will find

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Here you can add your timezone like

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
```

If you want to manage your timezone from `.env` file, then you can add below code in your `config.php` file.

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
```

and add the below line in your `.env` file.

```
APP_TIMEZONE='Europe/Paris'
```

Please check the link below for more information:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Answer (score 26):

After changing **app.php**, make sure you run:

```
 php artisan config:clear
```

This is needed to clear the cache of config settings. If you notice that your timestamps are still wrong after changing the timezone in your app.php file, then running the above command should refresh everything, and your new timezone should be effective.

Answer (score 12):

Please try this -
Create a directory 'config' in your lumen setup, and then create app.php file inside this 'config' dir. it will look like this -

```
<?php return ['app.timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles'];
```

Then you can access its value anywhere like this -

```
$value = config('app.timezone');
```

If it doesn't work, you can add this lines in routes.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

This worked for me!

Comment: This is not correct - putting `app.timezone` in the `app.php` config file is redundant as the `app` part of `config('app.timezone')` refers to the file name in the `config/` dir.

Comment: Okay @MattHumphrey , you can edit my answer if it seems incorrect to you.

Comment: Thanks. last one worked for me. It's very frustrating when the same lines of code works for someone and not for others.

Comment: @MahammadIsgandarli - Glad to know it worked for you :)

Comment: adding date_default_timezone_set to routes file worked for me just fine.

Comment: The `date_default_timezone_set` should be added to the `boot` method of _AppServiceProvider.php_ instead of _routes.php_ because it makes more sense although it works either way.

Comment: Yes, and also otherwise, if you're using Laravel and you have multiple route files, you'd have to put the call in all of them!

Answer (score 10):

> Go to config -> app.php and change 'timezone' => 'Asia/Jakarta',

(this is my timezone)

Answer (score 7):

In Lumen's .env file, specify the timezones. For India, it would be like:

```
APP_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'
DB_TIMEZONE = '+05:30'
```

Answer (score 7):

There is an easy way to set the default timezone in laravel or lumen.

This is helpful while working in multiple environments where you can use different timezone based on each environment.

1. Open **.env** file present inside the your project directory
2. Add `APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Kolkata` in `.env` (Your can choose any timezone from the [supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php))
3. Open **app.php** present inside **bootstrap** folder of your project directory
4. Add `date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'));` in `app.php`.

*With this change your project will take your **.env** set timezone and if there is nothing set then take **UTC** by default.*

> After modifying the time zone setting run command **`php artisan config:clear`** so that your changes reflect in your application

Answer (score 6):

Use php time zones from php manual
[Php time zones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

For example mine i changed from the UTC value in config/app.php with

```
'timezone' => 'Africa/Nairobi',
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case (reading a date from a MySQL db in a Lumen 5.1 project) the only solution that worked is using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)  to set timezone of variables:

```
    $carbonDate = new Carbon($dateFromDBInUTC);
    $carbonDate->timezone = 'America/New_York';
    return $carbonDate->toDayDateTimeString(); // or $carbonDate->toDateTimeString() for ISO format
```

Using `DB_TIMEZONE=-05:00` in the `.env` file almost worked but does not handle DST changes.

Using the `APP_TIMEZONE=America/New_York` in the `.env` file had no effect on a timezone value retrieved in a Lumen 5.1 webapp from a MySQL database, but it works in Lavarel 5.1.

Also Lumen didn't read at all the  `[lumen_project]/config/app.php` file that I created (it didn't complain when I put a syntax error there).

Using `date_default_timezone_set` didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried many other solutions (including the ones you've listed in your summary) and nothing worked. Setting the timezone within the Controller as a Carbon variable seems to have worked for now.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to edit de app.php file in config directory
Just find next lines

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

And.. chage it for:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
```

Answer (score 5):

**By default time zone of laravel project is **UTC***

- you can find time zone setting in **App.php** of **config folder**

**'timezone' => 'UTC',**

now change according to your time zone for me it's Asia/Calcutta

so for me setting will be **'timezone' => 'Asia/Calcutta',**

- After changing your time zone setting run command **php artisan config:cache**

*for time zone list visit this url https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp

Answer (score 1):

you can find time zone setting in config/App.php
put something like this:

```
'timezone' => 'Africa/Bujumbura',
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the app.php was here `/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/app.php` but I also could change it from the `.env` file where it can be set to any of the values listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp) (PHP original documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Open the **config/App.php** file and update the timezone value  with  *'Europe/Paris'*

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
```

Then clear the config cache by running the below artisan command

```
 php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

## Laravel 9 Change Timezone changing/setting

Go go, config\app.php  -- file in your laravel directory

Where you will get an option --   'timezone' => 'UTC'

Change this parameter with youy relevent one,
Ex:    'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',

Answer (score -3):

Just changing **APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Colombo** in .env and run 
*php artisan lumen-config:cache* 
worked for me in lumen 5.7

Answer (score -6):

I modify it in the .env APP_TIMEZONE.

For Colombia: APP_TIMEZONE = America / Bogota
also for paris like this: APP_TIMEZONE = Europe / Paris

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.europe.php