# setlocale() in Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to localize data output.

```
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'et_EE.utf8');
 echo strftime("%H:%M %A, %d %B");
```

Instead Estonian language I get it in English format.
But if I do it in Job class - all ok.
In my Controller I didn't call `setlocale()` anymore just once `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'et_EE.utf8');`

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem you face, would you clarify ?

Comment: I need to get result in this example in Estonian Langugage  (date) but instead i got English variant.But if this code executed in Job class (laravel framework) - all ok.Problem only if I try it to do in Controller.

Comment: Oh, Okay..
Can you tell me what's the underlying operating system ?
As In linux it depends on the installed locales

Comment: Yes it's Linux and I have this locale (locale -a)  "et_EE.utf8" in the list.And if try to test it for example:  php -r ' setlocale(LC_TIME, 'et_EE.utf8');' I reach goal.But in my controller somethig wrong.Also when I testet it on my Win platform - all go well.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout links, it describe you both way configuration level setting as well as change timezone on the fly 
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884388/change-timezone-in-lumen-or-laravel-5)

[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/timezone-config-change-on-the-fly?page=0)

Comment: Question is not about timezone. for expl.: 1 february Wednesday  in Estonian should be display  - 1 Veebruar Kolmapäev

Comment: Okay, then you need to get timezone of user and convert data into user timezone everytime. Please check this code it convert data into timezone which is stored in Cookie  `$new_date = \Carbon::createFromFormat($format,$date)->setTimezone(Cookie::get('timezone'));
      if($type=='object'){
        return $new_date;
      }else{
        return $new_date->format($format);
      }`

Comment: You need to convert language or you need to convert timezone of date?

Comment: I don't need timezone, I need to display localized date from strftime("%H:%M %A, %d %B");

Comment: Okay, then you need to use [package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) which set language based on URL like example.com/en, example.com/fr etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's so strange for me that the set_locale works in a place and not the another, because php doesn't interfere with `set_locale` as it directly calls C function with the same name.

On Linux, locales must be installed in your system.
To check which locales are supported use the command
`locale -a`

you must see a list like this

```
en_US.utf8
et_EE.utf8
```

To add a locale, it differs from system to another

For ubuntu check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server)

For Arch and maybe others, edit the `/etc/locale.gen` and un-comment the wanted locale. then run `sudo locale-gen`

Voila your code will work..

Comment: Exacly - it works perfec from some other classes in laravel.But in controller where I call it I put result in log-file - and what I see - echo setlocale(LC_TIME, 'et_EE.utf8');  Return me empty result :(

Comment: `set_locale` is part of php not laravel at all.. so your talk makes non-sense for me.. this needs more digging.
Any way try this answer and tell me if it worked out.