# change time zone in full Laravel project to UTC

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timezone

I set the time zone in app.php to 'UTC' and also in database.php set to 'UTC' but still, the dates are saving in the local time zone, please can help anyone?
I have try this

app.php

```
'timezone'=> env('TIMEZONE','UTC'),
```

Database.php

```
'mysql' => [
    'timezone'  => '+00:00',
],
```

Comment: Is your Database time already set in UTC too?

Comment: after change `time zone` from config you need to run `php artisan config:clear` then it will effect

Comment: You may find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884388/change-timezone-in-lumen-or-laravel-5)

Comment: @StevanLai  yes I already set the time to UTC and to the database also

Comment: @PunitGajjar I have tried but not working

Comment: @UdayAjani , did you clear the cache as informed ?