# Change timezone of function date() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, time

Using this function in laravel `date('d-m-Y_H.i.s')` I get the date in the expected format but I'm not able to change the timezone in order to get my current time. It's one hour delayed.

I have already tried to change timezone unsuccessfully in **app.php**  `'timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid';`
Also tried in **Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php** `date_default_timezone_set($config->get('app.timezone', 'Europe/Madrid'));`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Timezone in Lumen or Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884388/change-timezone-in-lumen-or-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Option1: Change UTC to user's timezone on frontend.

Option2: Change on backend.

[How to manage timezone in Laravel](https://brainlet.medium.com/manage-timezones-in-laravel-utc-to-users-timezone-305274278096)